# gform_after_submission not working as expected

Tags: user-meta, plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to augment a value to the `wp_user_meta` table, utilizing Gravity Forms. And I'm not having any luck. I had a version of this working on `gform_pre_submission` (though without the class-sniffing) but I want to do this after submission since there will be PayPal involved and don't want to post until the payment is verified.

I was trying to use cssClass as a filter so the other developers are free to create as many gravity forms as they want, provided they use the classes `product_name` and `product_price`

Unfortunately, my database is just filling up with fails right now.

```
// hook onto gravity forms and update payment history field
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'payment_history_handler', 10, 2);
function payment_history_handler($entry, $form){

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$payment_history = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'payment_history', true);

foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){
    if(strpos($field['cssClass'], 'payment_name') === true){
        $payment_name = $entry[$field['id']];;
    } else {
        $payment_name = 'fail';
    }
    if(strpos($field['cssClass'], 'payment_price') === true){
        $payment_price = $entry[$field['id']];
    } else {
        $payment_price = 1;
    }
}

if(!empty($payment_name) && !empty($payment_price)){
    $payment_history[] = array('date' => date('U'), 'name' => $payment_name, 'price' => $payment_price);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'payment_history', $payment_history);
}

}
```

The classes are in place, as seen by this sample of my output:

```
<div class='gform_body'>
  <ul id='gform_fields_4' class='gform_fields top_label description_below'>
    <li id='field_4_1' class='gfield    payment_name           gfield_contains_required' >
      <label class='gfield_label' for='input_4_1'>What Thing are you choosing?<span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label>
      <div class='ginput_container'>
        <select name='input_1' id='input_4_1'  class='medium gfield_select' tabindex='1' >
          <option value='The first one' >The first one</option>
          <option value='The second one' >The second one</option>
          <option value='The third one' >The third one</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id='field_4_2' class='gfield    payment_price           gfield_contains_required' >
      <label class='gfield_label' for='input_4_2'>Price<span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label>
      <div class='ginput_container'>
        <input name='input_2' id='input_4_2' type='text'  value='' class='medium' tabindex='2'   />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is testing to see where every field on the form has class 'payment_name'. If you instead only want to find one field with class 'payment_name', then you need to break out of the for loop once you've found that field.

Also, [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) only returns `false` or an integer index into the haystack where it found the needle, not `true`; test instead for `strpos($field['cssClass'], 'payment_name') !== false`

Comment: Nice. This is working now. I'm actually looking for `payment_name` in one field and `payment_price` in another. I suppose once both of these are defined I can abort. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone finds this, a good way to break was to move the `if(!empty())` part of the code up into the loop and add a break statement beneath it, so as soon as both variables are defined, it does the work and stops looking. Thanks again @webaware